# Why does the hypotenuse of half the triangle (formed from a circle) ≈ pi * r?

Tags: calculus, triangles, pi

Just a while ago, while feeling bored, I took a pen and pencil, and started doing some math. After a while of doing something I found out that the hypotenuse of half the triangle (formed from a circle) ≈ pi * r
Here's how I got to that:

1. Convert the circle into a triangle
2. Now, the radius is the height of the triangle, and the circumference is the base of the triangle
3. Next we replace the radius with r (for simplicity), and replace the circumference with its formula (2 pi * r)
4. Next we divide the triangle in half (making identical 2 triangles)
5. Now the base of the triangle is half (pi * r), but the height is the same (r)
6. Now we try to calculate the hypotenuse -- 
   h = sqrt( (r)^2 + (pi * r)^2 )

   #### Note: sqrt means square root
7. Now we add in the values and calculate

For some reason, the hypotenuse ≈ pi * height
For example:
radius(h) = 3 cm
sqrt( (r)^2 + (pi * r)^2 ) 
= sqrt( (3)^2 + (3.14 * 3)^2 ) 
= sqrt( 9 + (9.42)^2 ) 
= sqrt( 9 + 88.7364 ) 
= sqrt( 97.7364 ) 
= 9.88617216116

Which approximately equals:
pi * r
= 3.14 * 3
= 9.42

Please tell me if I'm missing something super obvious.

Comment: How does one convert a circle into a triangle? Also, \$\sqrt{r^2+(\pi r)^2}\$ will print as $\sqrt{r^2+(\pi r)^2}$.

Comment: @Don Thousand my guess is that he's exscribing a circle with a triangle. Could be wrong.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Possible. But I'd like clarification from OP.

Comment: @DonThousand This is a video "sort of" replicating what I meant. The only difference being, I made it an isosceles triangle. 
[link](https://youtu.be/GNcFjFmqEc8?t=129)

Comment: @DonThousand Found a better representation: [link](https://youtu.be/WUvTyaaNkzM?list=PL0-GT3co4r2wlh6UHTUeQsrf3mlS2lk6x&t=104)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be forming an isosceles triangle by "unrolling" a circle a distance equal to its circumference to form the base of a triangle with height equaling the radius.

Then the length of the two congruent sides equals $\sqrt{r^2+\pi^2r^2}=r\sqrt{1+\pi^2}$.

Can you see now why this "approximately" equals $\pi r$?